# Can we use non base-called fast5 files in poretools?

Tags: minion, albacore

I run the MinION MinKNOW without the live base-calling option. We know there is Metrichor and Albacore to perform base-calling after this process. However, I have not done any base-calling yet.

My question is: Is it possible to use directly the `fast5` files with `poretools` to extract a fastq file without doing any previous base-calling process? I tried it and I get an empty fastq file.

My `reads` directory only contains the `fast5` folder and I run:

`poretools fastq fast5/ > output.fastq`

Any ideas why do I get an empty file? What is the difference between base-called `fast5` and non-base-called `fast5` files?

Now I am trying to do base-calling with Albacore to see if I get a fastq file.

Comment: You’ve edited the title - I should add that poretools can work with non base-called FAST5 files with some of its options, but not the fastq option. Some of the metadata options will function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, poretools does not do basecalling. The `poretools fastq` command can be used to extract the FASTQ information from the basecalled FAST5 file (via MinKNOW live-basecalling or albacore). Alternatively, both of these basecallers can export a FASTQ file directly if desired.

The difference between a basecalled FAST5 and a nonbasecalled FAST5 is the presence of the FASTQ within the file. This can be directly viewed using an HDF5 viewer, like [h5dump](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/Tools.html) from the commandline, or [HDFView](https://support.hdfgroup.org/products/java/hdfview/) from the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Albacore can be used to create a fastq, directly from your fast5 files. As such there is no more reason to use poretools, expect perhaps for getting some metadata. With regards to metadata I would like to add that the sequencing_summary.txt generated by albacore also contains a lot of metadata.